# Proving that odd function has zero integral using Riemann sums

Tags: integration, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[-a,a]$, where $a>0$. Use Riemann
>   sums to prove that if $f$ is an odd function,
>   then$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx=0$$

[image: Using Riemann Sum for proving]

Very unsure about how to use Riemann sum to prove that f is an odd function. Any solutions/hints on how to get started on this question will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is not to show that f is odd, this is a condition.

Comment: Yes, @Yongyong is correct. You are told a priori that $f$ is odd, therefore use a Riemann sum approach to show that the integral over a symmetric range identically vanishes.

Comment: Also, if you are sure that $f$ is indeed integrable on $[-a,a]$ then you should show (or, I suppose explain) that $f$ is separably integrable on $[-a,0]$ and $[0,a]$. So my advice would be partition on $[-a,0]$ and explain how to transform into Riemann Sums on $[0,a]$.

Answer (score 4):

If $f(x)$ is odd, then $f(-x)=-f(x), \; \forall x \in \mathbb R$.

$$\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^{0}{f(x)}\,dx+\int_{0}^{a}{f(x)}\,dx$$
Now
$$\int_{0}^{a}{f(x)}\,dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}}$$
But

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^{0}{f(x)}\,dx &= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(-x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}} \\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{-f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}} \\
&= -\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}} \\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
\therefore \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx&=\int_{-a}^{0}{f(x)}\,dx+\int_{0}^{a}{f(x)}\,dx \\
&= -\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}}+\lim_{n \to \infty}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{f(x_{i}^{*})\Delta x}} \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$